# Intel Fortran Compiler in XCode 8.3.2

Tags: xcode, fortran, intel-fortran

Did anyone try to add Intel Fortran Compiler to the latest XCode (version 8.3.2)? I can't find the compiler on the list. I tried to re-install the compiler entirely, linking it again to the XCode location, but nothing helped. Any idea why this happens? (I was also unable to run the simple code via terminal on Mac with the ifort command, seems like it can't link the libraries location, even though I updated the environmental variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beta test compiler release notes do indicate that Xcode 8.2 is the latest supported version, as it is for the 2017u2 released compiler.  Intention to offer an update 2 of the beta has been mentioned.  Each minor update to Xcode apparently requires specific modifications and testing of Intel compilers.

Comment: Is there any way to work around this issue? Maybe revert to the older version of XCode somehow, or anything else?

Comment: Intel stated today that Xcode 8.3 will be supported in future compiler releases, later this month (May 2017) however several important Fortran features (e.g. MODULE) will remain without Xcode support.